# "got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop" error while using websocket.send(msg) in a while

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, runtime-error, python-asyncio

I'm using websocket to send and receive messages in python. I've used "websocket.send(msg)" to send messages in these forms:

```
await ws.send(message)
```

and

```
asyncio.run(ws.send(message))
```

inside a while loop in which I first check whether the connection is alive and then send messages using these commands. In all of them, if number of sending times is low, there is no problem but when it increases, I get this exception for sending message

```
Task <Task pending coro=<RunSocket() running at <ipython-input-1-b17eaf75a3de>:182> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at D:\Anaconda\InstallationFolder\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:158]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

"Notice that RunSocket is one of my functions' name"

Then I get this error:

```
got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

Also I tried this code:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(await ws.send(message))
```

But it didn't send any messages. Can anyone help me with this error ? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

> got Future  attached to a different loop

When you create some async object it is attached to a [current](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.set_event_loop) event loop (main thread has one by default).
The async object is expected to be worked with while the same event loop is current.
`asyncio.run` creates new event loop and set it is a current.
Result is - you've attached async object to one event loop, but trying to use it with another one. This where error comes from.

To avoid it, you should create async object after new event loop is created by `asyncio.run`:

```
async def main():
    ws = ...  # create object after asyncio.run is started
    res = ws.send(message)
    return res

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't understand why it works without any problem for about 2 minutes and then this error appears.

Comment: @sinaranjkeshzade it's hard to say precisely without having a reproducible code, but may be the mentioned async object is created inside `ws` and is used not immediately so that it takes time for error to happen.

Comment: What does "create some async object" refer to: defining a coroutine with `async def coro()` or calling it with `coro()`? Is it possible to change that, in order to execute a coroutine in a different event loop inside a different thread for example?

Comment: @JeanMonet it refer to calling async function - `coro()`. Once the coroutine function is called, async object (or coroutine object) is created and attached to an event loop. If you want to await something in a different event loop, you should call `coro()` when different event loop is set to default. See this answer for an example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301233/1113207