# Run asyncio loop in a separate thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a component of an application that needs to run an IOLoop in a separate thread. I try to achieve that by creating an new IOLOOP in a background Thread and starting the loop. My original use case it keep scheduling a bunch of async tasks periodically.

To achieve this, I:

- Create an event loop in a background thread.
- Start the thread and call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._start, self._loop)`

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress

from threading import Thread


class AsyncScheduler(object):
    """
    Async Schedule Class.

    This class:
        - Will run on  a separate event loop on a separate thread.
        - Will periodically(every minute) schedule tasks for Requester.
    """

    def __init__(self, batch_manager, requester):
       
        self._requester = requester
        self._is_started = False
        self._tasks = []
        self._loop = None
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        """
        Start a new event loop in a thread.
        call eventloop.run(self._start)
        :return:
        """
        print("STARTING")
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        # start new loop in thread.
        Thread(target=self._loop.run_forever).start()
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._start, self._loop)

    def stop(self):
        if self._loop:
            # cancel tasks
            self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self._stop)
            # stop the loop.
            self._loop.stop()

    

    async def _start(self):
        """
        Create three tasks for 3 API versions.
        Schedule Each tasks on the event loop using
        asyncio.gather.
        :return:
        """
        versions = [1, 2, 3]
        print("ASYNC START")

        if not self._is_started:
            self._is_started = True
            for version in versions:
                self._tasks.append(
                    self.create_task(60, version)
                )
            await asyncio.gather(*self._tasks)


    async def _stop(self):
        for task in self._tasks:
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                await task

    async def execute(self, api_version):
        """
        This method gets the batch to be executed and
        tells the requester to run it.
        :param api_version:
        :return:
        """
        
        await self._requester.run()

    async def create_task(self, sleep_time, api_version):
        """
        Calls the tasks in infinite loop.
        :param sleep_time:
        :param api_version:
        :return:
        """
        while True:
            print("EVER CALLED")
            await self.execute(api_version)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Steps done in the code:

- Call `start` from `init`
- In `start`, create an `eventloop` within a new thread and start the loop with an `awaitable`.

I thought this is the way to use an event loop inside a separate thread. Alas, but my awaitbale `sel._start` is never called and I get an error  `[A coroutine object is required]`

Any ideas, what am I messing up here?

Comment: An event loop can be run per process. So use multiprocessing instead of threading if you need two or more loops in your application.

Comment: I already have one `event loop` thats super busy with a separate set of IO with different rpm. I know I can borrow that event loop here without blocking anything but we would want to see if having a separate IO LOOP for other set of IO is gonna help us or not?

Comment: If you're not running an asynchronous server that maybe needs a whole loop only under its usage, then you are probably looking for `asyncio.create_task` or `asyncio.gather` like functions.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan Not correct.  You can have one event loop running per threading.Thread, and many threads per multiprocessing.Process, each containing its own asyncio event_loop.

Comment: Your error is that `self._start` is not a coroutine object, it is a function that RETURNS a coroutine object.  Your code will run if you add parenthesis: `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._start(), self._loop)`

Comment: @PaulCornelius, what threads do you mean - OS Threads or Python Threads? If Python threads, I am afraid you're wrong. I had such practice when my first task was blocking the loop and using it only for handling its async methods. Also, in the scope of the application, I needed to make some HTTP requests using `aiohttp`, which needs an event loop. I was trying to create a new one in a separate thread, but trying that, I got errors that I cannot have multiple loops, so I had to create it in a separate process.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan  See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298922/how-do-i-set-the-asyncio-event-loop-for-a-thread-in-python.  Two Python threads, each with its own event loop, and only one Process.  Please run that program and tell me if it doesn't work.  I think I was pretty clear that I was referring to threading.Thread and multiprocessing.Process.  On Windows, the OS recognizes Python Threads the same as OS threads, and displays the correct count in the Task Manager.  What are you referring to?  Perhaps I don't understand your terminology.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, thanks for sharing the answer. I learned something very useful.